# Creating a file in a folder

Tags: io, rust

How do I create a file in a certain folder in Rust?

I have tried the following approaches:

```
let f = File::create(Path::new(format!("{}{}","/files/",filename).as_str()));

let f = File::create(format!("{}{}","/files/",filename));
```

Both result in:

```
The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
```

I have managed to create the file in the same directory as the executable with:

```
let f = File::create(format!("{}",filename));
```

So how do I go about creating files in a specific directory?

`ls` on basefolder:

```
PS C:\trust\svd2rust\target\debug> ls

    Directory: C:\trust\svd2rust\target\debug

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2017-01-24     12:13                .fingerprint
d-----       2017-01-24     12:13                build
d-----       2017-01-26     10:06                deps
d-----       2017-01-24     12:13                examples
d-----       2017-01-26     07:18                files
d-----       2017-01-24     12:13                incremental
d-----       2017-01-24     12:13                native
-a----       2017-01-24     12:13              0 .cargo-lock
-a----       2017-01-26     10:06        1079240 libsvd2rust.rlib
-a----       2017-01-24     21:08          27608 log.rs
-a----       2017-01-24     13:55          27372 log2.rs
-a----       2016-08-23     15:07         565888 STM32F401x.svd
-a----       2016-08-23     15:07         912360 STM32F401xE.svd
-a----       2016-08-23     15:07        1907985 STM32F40x.svd
-a----       2017-01-26     10:06       11761561 svd2rust.exe
```

Comment: Does the `/files` directory exist?

Comment: Yes it has been created

Comment: Can you post a *complete* minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Note: you should be able to use `Path::new("/files/").join(Path::new(&filename))` as argument, without invoking the `format` macro or calling `as_str()` at the end (you should avoid strings as they validate that their content is valid Unicode and note all files are).

Comment: Regarding your question: it's pretty difficult to diagnose the issue without knowing what the file system looks like. What does `ls -ls /files/` return? (Post both the command you actually play and its output).

Comment: Matthieu, no luck with:
let f = File::create(Path::new("/files/").join(Path::new(&filename)));
Same error.

ls /files/ gives an empty response:
PS C:\trust\svd2rust\target\debug> ls .\files\
PS C:\trust\svd2rust\target\debug>

Comment: Can you print out the filename instead of passing it to `File::create`, to check that it's what you expect?  Where is `filename` coming from (e.g. does it have a trailing newline from input, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I can create files in the base folder so I am guessing it is fine:

"I have managed to create the file in the same directory as the executable with:

let f = File::create(format!("{}",filename));"
Edit: Printing the filename also works

Comment: Apart from possible problems with Windows paths using `\` instead of `/` (I'm never sure when the latter is also ok), wouldn't `/files/` point to `c:\files\` rather than `.\files\`?

Comment: You are correct! Using files/ instead of /files/ solves the problem! Thanks alot

Comment: @MatthieuM. `Path::new("/files/").join(&filename)` should be sufficient (`AsRef<Path>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "files/" instead of "/files/" solved the problem.

It seems "/files/" references to the absolute path of C:\files, while "files/" references to the relative path of the executable.

So when using "/files/" it did't work since there was no folder C:\Files.